# preprocessor fails to reflect project settings in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

For some reason I've set a preprocessor variable, but it doesn't reflect in the build.

Here is the project build setting:

[image: project build setting]

The desired path is grayed out:

[image: namespace reference]

This is not just a cosmetic problem. It won't build:

[image]

**EDIT**: Sometimes when I close/reload the project the variable is gone, but I always see it in the project file when I edit it:

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;MISMO32</DefineConstants>
```

Comment: What configuration are you building in?

Comment: @DaveShaw: I am building in Debug

Comment: That `#if` shown is in the same project, right? (I have to ask)

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?
VS gets tangled sometimes and a good ol' build-clean then restart VS does wonders.

Comment: @user1: Fair question. I double-checked and confirmed they are.

Comment: @Daniel: You are right it does! I've tried this from VS2010 and VS2012. I removed the variable, saved, build, then retried it with the variable back again. No success.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our custom build system wipes out the pre-processor directives at compile time.

Not much of a learning opportunity for others, unfortunately.